# How to extract a subdirectory of one git repository into its own repo, keeping history and all branches?

Tags: git, branch, git-filter-branch

I have a large repo with a subfolder A that I would like to extract into it's own repo. I'd like to keep commit history for both the master branch and all (or at least several) release branches. I tried using `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter A`, but this seems to only affect the master branch (I can checkout other branches, but they still have the full original set of files). What's the best way to do this?

EDIT: I tried running `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter A/ -- --all`. This runs for awhile and then hangs indefinitely.

I then tried running `git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter A/ -- --branches=*`. This runs successfully. However, when I use git checkout to checkout a different branch, that branch does not seem to have been filtered.

Comment: Did you even take a minimum look at `git help filter-branch` or `man git-filter-branch` ?

Comment: `git filter-branch` takes an optional argument called `[<rev-list options>...]` in the man page, in which you can specify multiple branches.

Comment: @Jubobs: I tried running with -- --all, and it processes all commits (prints out 658/658) but then hangs. When I CTRL+C, it leaves behind a git-rewrite folder but otherwise there are no changes...

Comment: @StefanNäwe: I did look at the docs. Can you point me to the part that addresses my question?